# Webpack 2 not resolving entry point in webpack.config.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, webpack-2

I'm receiving an error when attempting to build my application via webpack 2.

My app folder structure looks like this:

```
/
| - dist/
|
| - src/
|   |  
|   | - modules/
|   |   |
|   |   | - module1.js
|   |
|   | - index.js *
|
| _ webpack.config.js
|
| - package.json
```

The relevant portion of my `webpack.config.js` file is here:

```
/**
 * Requires
 */
const path = require('path');


/**
 * Variables
 */
const PATHS = {
  src: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
  dist: path.join(__dirname, 'dist')
};


/**
 * Configuration
 */
module.exports = {

  entry: {
    context: PATHS.src,
    main: './index.js'
  },

  ....
}
```

When I run `npm run build`, which is my script alias for `webpack --display-error-details`, I receive the following error details:

```
ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve './index.js' in <my project path>
resolve './index.js' in <my project path>
  using description file: <my project path>/package.json (relative path: .)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
```

Now, I'm slowly learning webpack and this could very well be a simple misunderstanding of how webpack's `context` property works. `PATHS.src` equals the absolute path of my project's `src` directory, and my entry point is `./index.js`, which is inside of that directory. Can anybody help me identify why I'm receiving this error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try with `'./src/index.js'`

Comment: Interesting. I did this, and I get no error. But why? If I pass `PATHS.src` to the `context` parameter, doesn't webpack start at that file path AND THEN look for the entry point? If I print out the value of `PATHS.src`, I will get `path/to/project/root/src`.

Comment: `context` shouldn't be a property of `entry`. Move it a level up.

Comment: Wow, huge oversight on my part! Thank you @DraganS